# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_app.urls' in django

Tags: python, django, heroku

after deploying site on heroku ,it's showing Internal server error.
for debug I made "debug=true" and I found this error :
`"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_app.urls' "`

I've added my app in installed app list

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'my_app',
]
```

my_project urls :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('my_app.urls'))
 ]
```

my_app urls:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.home ),
    
]
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def home(request):
    return render(request,'index.html')
```

site running on local server while  `debug = true`
but not running while `debug=false`(showing server error )

so how to fix this error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_app.urls' "

What did I miss. Any help/suggestion will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Hi, did you already executed pip freeze > requirements.txt before deploying to heroku?

Comment: hello , I did but I remove this 2 thing from there ''Twisted==21.o2.0" and "twisetd-iocpsupport==1.0.1" cuz these 2 thing causing errors while deploying...do i need to install them ?

Comment: I had an issue with a plug in or package and the problem was with the virtual environment , I was using pipenv, so instead of doing pip install xxxx I had to do pipenv install xxx and then execute the pip freeze, what I don´t get from your issue is that it is complaining of the main app, that is what I understand from reading your question, right?

Comment: I think your are missing this in my_project urls: from django.conf.urls import include, url

Comment: I tried but it's not working sir, I'm still getting this error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folio.urls' And I'm not using virtual environment(pipenv)

Comment: you included url, right? also, is folio.urls a new message error?

Comment: yes !! actually ' folio' is my app name. for example I used  ' my_app ' and you are right .and still now I'm getting" No module named  'my_app.url '  "

Comment: In your my_app.urls try adding: from django.conf import settings

Comment: still getting this error...

Comment: can you share your project structure?

Comment: btw I just fixed that error by restarting that project thanks for your kindest replies...but wait 
new error occur ..And it says " application error " in heroku app page
And I tried to find the error by "heroku logs --tail --app my_app_name"
but the logs doesn't make any sense to me I don't know What does this mean pls check the screenshots (https://prnt.sc/129v9e7)(https://prnt.sc/129v3t2) (https://prnt.sc/129v62a)

Comment: you are getting another ModuleNofFoundError mpfol.wsgi I don´t know what that is, do you see that in your requirements.txt?

Comment: no I don't  see it in requirement.txt  !my requirement.txt file --() Procfile(https://prnt.sc/12aoyub) what to do next ..? pls help and grateful to you for the kindest replies

Comment: no I don't see it in requirement.txt ! Procfile(prnt.sc/12aoyub) what to do next ..? pls help and grateful to you for the kindest replies

Comment: I just changed my procfile configuration into  this ()
but now the before error occur again "Internal server error" and after that I find the problem is " ModuleNotFoundError: No module named'mpfol.urls' " (mpfol is my application name)

Comment: forget to mention procfile is now
 "web: gunicorn pfol.wsgi" (pfol is project name)

Comment: and At the final moment I'm getting this error again " ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mpfol.urls'" again.....pls help sir

Answer (score 1):

you have to include your app information inside of your installed app section

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'my_app.apps.YOURAPPCONFIG NAME',
]
```

YOURAPPCONFIG NAME is in your apps.py, and copy the name of class and paste it.